# Data not adding points to chart, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadStart dataRead = new ThreadStart(readInData);
    ThreadStart appStart = new ThreadStart(startApp);
    Thread appThread = new Thread(appStart);
    Thread childThread = new Thread(dataRead);

    appThread.Start();
    childThread.Start(); 
}

public static void startApp()
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

public static void readInData()
{
    Form1 cls = new Form1();
    clock.Start();

    try
    {
        mySerialPort.PortName = "COM3";
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry! " + ex);
    }

    while (Continue)
    {
        string message = mySerialPort.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        if (message == "Altitude\r")
        {
            origAlt = mySerialPort.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(origAlt);
            Continue = false; 
        }
    }

    Continue = true;
    while (Continue)
    {
        TimeSpan timePassed = clock.Elapsed;
        string message = mySerialPort.ReadLine();

        if (stringComparer.Equals("Next\r", message))
        {
            Continue = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        if (message == "Altitude\r")
        {
            altitude = mySerialPort.ReadLine();
            cls.setChartData(altitude, timePassed.Seconds);

            Console.WriteLine(altitude);
        }
        else if (message == "Temperature\r")
        {
            temperature = mySerialPort.ReadLine();
            cls.setGuageData(temperature);

            Console.WriteLine(temperature);
        }
    }
}

public void setChartData(string alt, int seconds)
{
    chart1.Series["AltitudeChart"].Points.AddXY(seconds, alt);
    chart1.Update();
}
```

The function setChartData() that is being called by the thread above is running correctly, and when i place breakpoints it reaches this point clearly which you can see with intellisense that the past variables have values. For some reason, the point is not being added to the chart, or at least I can not visibly see if the point is being added. How can i fix this problem??

Before I started using multi-threading, this command worked, adding that point to the chart visibly. How could the multi threading be breaking that?

Comment: Where are you breaking loops?

Comment: I was breaking loops previously, no loops are being broken currently. The while loop never has the chance to receive continue = false

Comment: Are you sure SetChartData is on the UI thread?

Comment: You have Application.Run on a new Form1, and then in the ReadInData you make another new Form1 called cls, which you never show.  WinForm applications require the STAThread attribute, too.

Comment: yikes I see that error now, thank you. But i guess my problem is that i still cannot run my data collection in the background while editing graphs in the UI? Any thoughts on how to fix that?